# How to show posts in custom page template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, templates, post

I am trying to make my custom page template,in which i display post with custom styles, i don't know how to show posts in this custom page template,here i am attaching my simple code for custom page template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Template
*/
get_header();

  //custom code for post is here
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Its very easy You first add a page and assign it to the template you just made and use simple loop or you can use WP Query where you can add all your styles you want to add and have fun with it....   This may help you immensly https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use page template similar to this and make full use of the codes over here writing with our own classes and style you are referring to :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Template
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
  <div id="content" role="main">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  </header>

  <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->

  <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
 </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `WP_Query()` to add a custom loop to your page template. You can find a few examples in the [WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)